# Find the maximum of the facts in the clips SATISFYING THE CONDITION

Tags: conditional-statements, clips

I need a function that will search for the maximum value of only the facts that satisfy my conditions.

```
(deftemplate tax
(field det (type SYMBOL))
(field oper (type INTEGER))
(field machine (type INTEGER))
(field time (type INTEGER))
)

  (deffacts tax

    (tax (det A) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 10))
    (tax (det A) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
    (tax (det B) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 8))
    (tax (det B) (oper 2) (machine 5) (time 4))
    (tax (det C) (oper 1) (machine 4) (time 10))
    (tax (det C) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
    (tax (det D) (oper 1) (machine 3) (time 6))
    (tax (det D) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
    (tax (det E) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 7))
    )

    (deffunction my-predicate (?fact1 ?fact2)
       (< (fact-slot-value ?fact1 time) (fact-slot-value ?fact2 time)))


    (deffunction find-max (?template ?predicate)
        (bind ?max FALSE)
        (do-for-all-facts ((?f ?template)) TRUE

        (test (eq oper 2))    ; It's my conditions. This may be something else.

        (if (or (not ?max) (funcall ?predicate ?f ?max))
        then
            (bind ?max ?f)))
    (return ?max))

       (defrule find-max
       =>
       (bind ?tax (find-max tax my-predicate))
       (if ?tax
          then
          (printout t "Fact " (fact-slot-value ?tax machine ) " is the maximum" crlf)))
```

But I get an error in the function find-max and rule find-max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your find-max deffunction where you had TRUE, you need to place your condition there instead. The test CE element, (test (eq ?oper 2)), you placed within the function only work within the conditions of a rule.

```
(deffunction find-max (?template ?predicate)
   (bind ?max FALSE)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f ?template)) (eq (fact-slot-value ?f oper) 2)
      (if (or (not ?max) (funcall ?predicate ?f ?max))
         then
         (bind ?max ?f)))
    (return ?max))
```

For finding the minimum/maximum value, you can use the sort function to order the facts rather than defining a function to do this and then pull either the value from the beginning or the end of the list.

```
CLIPS> (sort my-predicate (find-all-facts ((?f tax)) (eq ?f:oper 2)))
(<Fact-2> <Fact-6> <Fact-8> <Fact-4>)
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve a more complex problem associated crossing the facts:

```
(deftemplate store
(field det (type SYMBOL))
(field oper (type INTEGER))
(field count (type INTEGER))
)

(deftemplate tax
(field det (type SYMBOL))
(field oper (type INTEGER))
(field machine (type INTEGER))
(field time (type INTEGER))
)

(deffacts store
(store (det A) (oper 1) (count 100))
(store (det B) (oper 1) (count 0))
(store (det A) (oper 1) (count 3))
(store (det B) (oper 1) (count 0))
(store (det A) (oper 2) (count 2))
(store (det B) (oper 2) (count 0))
(store (det A) (oper 2) (count 0))
(store (det B) (oper 2) (count 5))
(store (det A) (oper 2) (count 1))
(store (det B) (oper 1) (count 0))
)


(deffacts tax
(tax (det A) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 10))
(tax (det A) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
(tax (det B) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 8))
(tax (det B) (oper 2) (machine 5) (time 4))
(tax (det C) (oper 1) (machine 4) (time 10))
(tax (det C) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
(tax (det D) (oper 1) (machine 3) (time 6))
(tax (det D) (oper 2) (machine 2) (time 5))
(tax (det E) (oper 1) (machine 1) (time 7))
)

(deffunction my-predicate (?fact1 ?fact2)
   (< (fact-slot-value ?fact1 time) (fact-slot-value ?fact2 time)))


(deffunction find-max (?template ?predicate)
   (bind ?max FALSE)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f ?template)) (eq (fact-slot-value ?f oper) 2) ; and store:count = 0
   ;(do-for-all-facts ((?f ?template)) (eq (fact-slot-value ?f oper) 2) ; and ((?f2 ?template2)) (eq (fact-slot-value ?f2 count) 0)  - it's not is not correct


      (if (or (not ?max) (funcall ?predicate ?f ?max))
         then
         (bind ?max ?f)))
    (return ?max))

       (defrule find-max
       =>
       (bind ?tax (find-max tax my-predicate))
       (if ?tax
          then
          (printout t "Fact " (fact-slot-value ?tax oper ) " is the maximum"
```